# How do I build and run React Native Project on new MacBook in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am having issues attempting to run my React Native project on my new MacBook Pro. I transferred the project from my old MacBook and downloaded Xcode but I get the following error when trying to run the project.

"%HOME_DIRECTORY%/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

I have installed Homebrew, Watchman and ran pod install but the project is not launching in Xcode.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks.

Comment: Follow the official docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Don't forget to install (and select) the Xcode Command Line tools. Run `yarn / npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `package.json` file. There are a lot of dependencies in there. They must be installed. If there is no `node_modules` folder, where your `package.json` is located, they are *not* installed.

Installing the dependencies can be done by running `yarn install` or `npm install`, depending what package manager you use. Make sure you are in the folder where your `package.json` is located. Clean your `Build Folder` from `Xcode` and run it again. It should work.